# Getting a specific item to become unchecked by clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a custom drop down menu, in which I am using to fill a div with the selections when `.is(":checked")`. The divs are filling correctly, but I am having some trouble figuring out how to remove the selections in the div.

I think the reason I am having troubles is because the div is only filling with the inputs value. I am unsure of how to remove this value from the `proposal-type` div and then repopulate the drop list with the item removed, when clicking the x icon. So essentially, exactly the opposite as filling it.

Does anyone see what I have to do to remove the values in the `proposal-type` div, when clicking the x-icon for the `drop-item-selected` divs and then how to show the input again in the drop down?

Sorry if any of this is unclear. Please ask any questions if you need more clarity.

```js
$( '#proposal-type' ).click( function () {
    $( '#proposal-type-drop' ).addClass( 'active' );
} );
$( '.drop-item-input' ).on( 'change', function () {
    var proposalVal = "";
    var proposalHtml = "";
    $( '.drop-item-input' ).each( function () {
        if ( $( this ).is( ":checked" ) ) {
            proposalVal += $( this ).val();
            proposalHtml += '<div class="drop-item-selected"><span class="drop-item-close"></span>' + $( this ).val() + '</div>';
            $( this ).closest( 'label' ).fadeOut();
        };
        $( '#proposal-type' ).val( proposalVal ).html( proposalHtml );
        $( '#proposal-type-drop' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    } );
    //values
    var type = $( '.drop-item-input:checked' ).map( function () {
        return $( this ).val();
    } ).get().join( ', ' );
    console.log( type );
} );
//Uncheck/remove
$( '.drop-item-close' ).click( function () {
    $( this ).is( ":checked" ) === false;
    $( this ).closest( 'label' ).fadeIn();
    $( this ).closest( '.drop-item-selected' ).fadeOut();
} );
```

```css
#proposal-type {
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  height: 20px;
}
#proposal-type-drop {
  width: 45%;
  height
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#proposal-type-drop.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.drop-item {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.drop-item-close {
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url("https://www.wpclipart.com/signs_symbol/alphabets_numbers/outlined_alphabet/white_capitol/capitol_X_white.png");
 background-size: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.drop-item-input {
  display: none;
}
.drop-item-selected {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.proposal-text {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%;
  !important
}
#proposal-check {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="proposal-type" name="proposal_type" class="proposal-input" data-text="Make Selection"></div>
<div id="proposal-type-drop">
  <label class="drop-item">A<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="A"></label>
  <label class="drop-item">B<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="B"></label>
  <label class="drop-item">C<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="C"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your close function doesn't do anything. For example you have a div instead of a label. Also you have no input element.

Comment: @Huelfe Right. I am just unsure of how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your code was too difficult to understand, so I simplified it a little bit.

1. converted the input blocks to regular html divs.
2. converted the checkboxes to spans
3. on click event, I populated a hidden input array.

`disabled` inputs won't send data to the server, so I used this as an advantage for this kind of situation.

```js
// click event for selectable proposals, assigned them to document to keep the events after attach/detach
$(document).on("click", ".available-proposals .proposal", function(event) {
  // after fadeout
  $(this).fadeOut("medium", function() {
    // set the new container
    var newContainer = $(this).closest(".proposal-container").find(".selected-proposals");
    // detach the item and move it to the container of the selected ones 
    $(this).detach().appendTo(newContainer).fadeIn().css("display", "inline-block");
    // remove the disabled attribute, so it can send data
    $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  // remove sub event triggers
  event.preventDefault();
});

// click event for the X close labels in the selected proposals
$(document).on("click", ".selected-proposals .proposal .close", function(event) {
  // select the main proposal object, because the event sender is the close label.
  var $this = $(this).parent(".proposal");
  // find the new container (old container which has available items)
  var newContainer2 = $this.closest(".proposal-container").find(".available-proposals");
  // after fadeout
  $this.fadeOut("medium", function() {
    // detach the item and move it to the container of the selectable ones
    $this.detach().appendTo(newContainer2).fadeIn().css("display", "block");
    // add the disabled attribute to the input, so it can't send data to the server
    $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").attr("disabled","disabled");
  });
  // remove sub event triggers.
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.available-proposals .close {
  display: none;
}

.selected-proposals .close {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.available-proposals .proposal {
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.selected-proposals .proposal {
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.available-proposals {}

.selected-proposals {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected-proposals .proposal {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="proposal-container">
  <div class="selected-proposals"></div>
  <div class="available-proposals">
    <div class="proposal">A<span class="close">X</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_proposals[]" value="A" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
    <div class="proposal" data-value="B">B<span class="close">X</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_proposals[]" value="B" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
    <div class="proposal" data-value="C">C<span class="close">X</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_proposals[]" value="C" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```